# Распишите подробно последовательно, как работает данный запрос с EXISTS с подзапросом MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Увидел вот такой пример на одном сайте (http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_exists_predicate.html) и не понимаю, как он читается правильно. В примере была описана работа **EXISTS**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker
FROM Product AS lap_product
WHERE type = 'laptop' AND EXISTS (
  SELECT maker
  FROM Product
  WHERE type = 'printer' AND 
  maker = lap_product.maker
);
```

Запутался в этом запросе. Зачем-то написано *AS lap_product* , в который потом зачем-то лезут из подзапроса.
**Распишите, пожалуйста, подробно, как такой запрос выполняется (отрабатывает) по шагам**. Первое,... Второе,... **Есть ли в таком запросе какие-то проходы / циклы выполнения?**

Comment: Почитайте документацию на `EXPLAIN`

Comment: берем по очереди каждую запись из первого Product (который назвали lap_product, собственно для того и AS что бы их различать) и для нее проверяем существует ли запись в Product с типом принтер и таким же производителем. Если существует - выводим. Ну это если пытаться описать алгоритмом как бы это делалось на императивном ЯП.

Comment: А вообще постановка вопроса "_Есть ли в таком запросе какие-то проходы / циклы выполнения?_" в принципе не корректна, язык SQL предназначен для работы с множествами и у него нет никаких проходов и циклов. А то как именно он будет выполняться решит СУБД. Думать надо множествами "Взять производителей продуктов, которые выпускают лэптопы и при этом выпускают еще и принтеры"

Comment: я знаю, что в чистом sql нет циклов. но как-то же надо читать запросы и понимать, как они выполняются. вы написали "берем по очереди каждую запись " - это как бы цикл. я это и имел в виду

Comment: Что бы понимать запросы надо научиться мыслить множествами. Попытка раскладывания в памяти сложных запросов по циклам очень утомительна. серьезный запрос сток из 50 с десятком таблиц в виде циклов будет представлять из себя алгоритм из тысяч строк

Comment: Обычно почти прямой перевод с английского достаточно точно показывает суть происходящего "Выбери (select) уникальные (distinct) maker из (from) Product, далее именуемый (as) lap_product, где (where) type='laptop' И существует (exists) такая выборка (select) опять же из Product где производитель тот же, что и в рассматриваемой записи lap_product и при этом тип='printer'

Comment: везде пишут, что AS используется для того, чтобы столбец выборки назвать. А в моем примере AS идет аж после FROM